# Notebook cant boot into setup routines completly

Tags: windows-7, boot

a friend asked me to re-install his Notebook but i am running into troubles.

I have tryed multiple boot cd´s but none of them seems to work

- Windows 7 Professional (The desired new system)
- Ubuntu Live Cd
- Windows 8 Professional

All systems / setup routines can't load completly.

After the message "Hit any key to boot from cd / dvd" by Windows 7, it is stuck and I get a black screen - Nothing loads anymore

Ubuntu is stuck in the Ubuntu loading / boot screen. I turned off the computer after 20 minutes.

I still can boot from hard disk into Windows 7 Professional.

Thanks

**edit1**

- All discs are working in my own machine without problems

Answer (score 3):

If 3 CDs in the same drive are failing then try using a different method.

Option 1) an external CD Drive that you can buy for cheap and it is always good to have on hand just in case.

Option 2) try putting Ubuntu on a thumbdrive and boot from that.

Those will help at least narrow down a few things. I always carry an Ubuntu 8Gb thumbdrive in my backpack just in case.

Comment: Thanks, i solved the problem my self. I was able to execute the Windows 7 Prof setup while Windows 7 was running ... so I just run the setup from explorer. I don't know why that worked ... but it did.